# Difficulty with uniqueness part of Cantor's Intersection theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

**Theorem:** ( Cantor's intersection theorem ) Let $ (I_n) $ be a sequence of closed intervals on the real plane with the property $ I_{n+1} \subseteq I_n $ for all $ n \in \mathbb{N} $ and suppose $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |I_n| = 0 $ ( The limit is not on cardinality but on the length of the interval ). Then there exists a unique number $ c $ that belongs to all the intervals , meaning  $\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^\infty I_n = \{ c \} $.

**Proof from lecture:**
Denote $ I_n = [ a_n,b_n]$. The condition $ I_{n+1} \subseteq I_n $ implies that the sequence $ (a_n) $ is monotonically increasing and that the sequence $ (b_n) $ is monotonically decreasing. In addition, the given $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |I_n| = 0 $ is equivalent to $ | b_n - a_n | \rightarrow 0 $.
We need to show that there exists a unique point $ x $ that belongs to all the intervals, or equivalently that there exists a unique $ x $ such that $ a_n \leq x \leq b_n $ for all $ n \in \mathbb{N} $.
**Uniqueness**: If x,y are real numbers such that $ a_n \leq x \leq b_n $ and $ a_n \leq y \leq b_n $ then
$ 0 \leq | x - y | \leq | b_n - a_n | $ for all $ n \in \mathbb{N} $. The rightmost and leftmost sides in the last inequality both tend to zero so by sandwich theorem we get $ | x - y | = 0 $, meaning $ x=y $.
**Existence**: [ proof of existence ]

I haven't added the existence part because I understood it, I don't understand the uniqueness part though. How did they arrive to the inequality $ 0 \leq | x - y | \leq | b_n - a_n | $ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$(1) \quad a_n \le x \le b_n$

and

$(2) \quad -b_n \le -y \le -a_n$

We add (1) and (2) and get

$$-(b_n-a_n) \le x-y \le b_n-a_n$$

This gives the desired inequality.

Answer (score 1):

For each $n\in\Bbb N$, since $x,y\in[a_n,b_n]$, $|x-y|\leqslant b_n-a_n=|b_n-a_n|$.